# Reduce M query response time

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a quick question. So I am trying to automate the data that I receive via an FTP folder with power query. I receive the data via CSV files daily, and each of these files has 1000's of lines of data. Below is my code

```
    Source = Folder.Files("G:\Group\Custodian\FTP"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", "Column1 - Copy"),
    #"Extracted Text Range" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Column1 - Copy", each Text.Middle(_, 10, 2), type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Text Range", each [#"Column1 - Copy"] = "40"),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Source.Name", "Source.Name - Copy"),
    #"Extracted Text Range1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column1", {{"Source.Name - Copy", each Text.Middle(_, 0, 6), type text}}),
    #"Transform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Text Range1",{{"Source.Name - Copy", each Date.FromText("20"&_), type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Transform,{{"Source.Name - Copy", "AFB-FTP Delivery Date"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each Date.IsInCurrentWeek([#"AFB-FTP Delivery Date"]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

The above essentially opens all of the CSV folders that have in the range 10 to 12(MID('Data Range',10,2)) = 40 as seen in the code below:

```
 #"Extracted Text Range" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Column1 - Copy", each Text.Middle(_, 10, 2), type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Extracted Text Range", each [#"Column1 - Copy"] = "40"),
```

And then applies the below function, to be able to filter the data by date as in my CSV files the first 6 characters are always the date shown as "yymmdd". So I used the below to format it to "yyyymmdd" so that excel could identify it as date. And then I renamed it to  *AFB-FTP Delivery Date*

```
 #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Source.Name", "Source.Name - Copy"),
    #"Extracted Text Range1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column1", {{"Source.Name - Copy", each Text.Middle(_, 0, 6), type text}}),
    #"Transform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Text Range1",{{"Source.Name - Copy", each Date.FromText("20"&_), type date}}),
AFB-FTP Delivery Date
```

The issue that I am having is that for instance if I only want to see the files from this week. I filter the data on AFB-FTP Delivery Date to this week. And when I press load, the query goes through all of the files, instead of going to the ones that are in the date range that I've put. It shows me the right data but is super slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you filter the results from Folder.Files() based on the Date Modified column for the rough date range you are looking for as the second step in the query?

Comment: For example use Date.StartOfWeek(DateTime.LocalNow(), Day.Monday) and 
Date.EndOfWeek(DateTime.LocalNow(), Day.Sunday) for the date filters to get all modified files between Monday and Sunday of current week

Comment: @horseyride I have already done that through here #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each Date.IsInCurrentWeek([#"AFB-FTP Delivery Date"])). The issue is that the query doesn't only go through the filtered files; but it goes through all of the files  and then just shows me the information that was filtered. Any ideas on how to make the query only explore the filtered files?

Comment: You are filtering after loading all the files. I am suggesting filtering the list of files before expanding as the second step after Folder.Files()